# Displaying symbols correctly in legend in ArcGIS Desktop after PDF Export?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, export, pdf

I am trying to create some maps in which have some point symbols. when I export the layout to pdf, the symbols are not appear. I have read some similar questions in the group but were not helpful for my case. there is an example of the mentioned problem in below.

[image]

Comment: Is that custom or standard ArcGIS icons?

Comment: Standard ARCGIS  Deshtop (Basic) 10.3

Comment: What are you export settings (specifically under Format)?

Comment: It sounds like you may have a corrupt .mxd file.  I have had similar issues in the past and the only resolution was to recreate the .mxd file.

Comment: Thank you Zachary, you were right . I tried to make new mxd and now it works.